# Detect the completion of words and sentence

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

In the `<textarea>` I used `(ngModelChange)` to detect content change and send RestAPI to server. However if I send a, lets say, 1000 character paragraph, when I add a new 5-letter word, in fact it sends 1001 + 1002 + 1003 + 1004 + 1005 = 5015 characters to the server, which is completely unnecessary.

So I am trying to detect sentences completion (or word completion) so that only the new sentence (words) are sent (like the above example, only the 5 new characters are sent, or, at least only 1005 characters are sent).

The methods I have tried are: (Using `regex`, `.trim()` and `length`)

1. Detecting white space;
2. Detecting ',' and '.'
3. Compare the length of the current and previous string.

Though I don't know if this is the best method.

Are there better ways to detect word/sentence change in a `<textarea>`?

---

Summary: Although I don't want to consider update by time, it is still a nice way to consider. (Check the selected answer)

Comment: Please tag angular 2+ questions with angular and not angularjs. Thank you.

Comment: What about a debounce? Only send it after a few seconds of inactivity, maybe combined with the other methods you mentioned. Check ngModelOptions.

Comment: Why not do it based on a timer instead of changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique is to use a timeout that will only allow a request every couple of seconds or whatever interval

```
var timeoutFn;

function change() {
    console.log('change');
    clearTimeout(timeoutFn);
    timeoutFn = setTimeout(doApiRequest, 1000);
}

function doApiRequest() {
    console.log('apiRequest');
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    change()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I am missing anything, but I think, it is sufficient to check the last character entered to detect a word. If the last character is a letter ([a-z]) it is not a word; if it is anything else, the content before it up to the last non-letter is a word.

For sentences, I think it will be enough to detect '.' character. You get '.', you get end of a sentence. The content till the preceding '.' is your sentence.

I know this is very basic, but feel free to add on this.